# Identify and remove script tags injected by Google Tag Manager

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

I have a React app and I need to work with 2 GTM IDs inside the app: one ID for the general app and one ID for 1 specific route.

As per my testings, I noticed that resetting the Tag Manager instance won't remove the injected scripts and removing the instance won't do too, so my current guess is to identify and remove manually all injected scripts when navigating from/to the specific route and initialising the other instance again to inject.

In summary, I want to remove injected scripts from a Tag Manager instance when not needed anymore, as they would conflict with other scripts that will be injected from a secondary Tag Manager instance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm trying to hide some scripts that were injected by GTM on my Vue app. Seems like you had a similar problem.

Comment: @TinyTiger Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution, we happened to change the approach entirely.